# Convert from CHR to DATE in R

Tags: r

Hi I have a date column called 'date' in format 2021-11-02. I need to change this from CHR to DATE in order that I can work with it in date format (filters etc). The below throws no error message but doesn't seem to convert to date, can anyone please advise.

```
    Table %>%
    mutate(Table, date= as.Date(date, format= "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Do you have different formats in that date column?

Comment: Hi no they are all YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: You seem to be passing your data frame to `mutate` twice. Beyond that we don't have any information about your data or the result you're getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your code. Try this one:

```
Table %>%
mutate(date2 = as.Date(date, format= "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your date format is in `YYYY-MM-DD` (default ISO 8601), `as.Date()` does not need the `format` argument.

```
Table %>% dplyr::mutate(dateConverted = as.Date(date))
```